# How to measure area between 2 distribution curves in R / ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The specific example is that imagine x is some continuous variable between 0 and 10 and that the red line is distribution of "goods" and the blue is "bads", I'd like to see if there is value in incorporating this variable into checking for 'goodness' but I'd like to first quantify the amount of stuff in the areas where the blue > red

Because this is a distribution chart, the scales look the same, but in reality there is 98 times more good in my sample which complicates things, since it's not actually just measuring the area under the curve, but rather measuring the bad sample where it's distribution is along lines where it's greater than the red.

I've been working to learn R, but am not even sure how to approach this one, any help appreciated. [image]

EDIT
sample data:
http://pastebin.com/7L3Xc2KU <- a few million rows of that, essentially.

the graph is created with

```
graph <- qplot(sample_x, bad_is_1, data=sample_data, geom="density", color=bid_is_1)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have some [sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick , added a link to show the type of data I'm working with

Comment: In `base` graphics, `polygon` is the way to plot this difference.  To calculate it, find the intersection points of the two curves, or just find all points where "red" < "blue" and do a numerical integral of the difference between the functions over those ranges.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I ended up calculating the area of trapezoids between the curves. Is there an better way to do numerical integration with R when you have a list of points?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this is to calculate the area between the curve using simple trapezoids.  First we manually compute the densities

```
d0 <- density(sample$sample_x[sample$bad_is_1==0])
d1 <- density(sample$sample_x[sample$bad_is_1==1])
```

Now we create functions that will interpolate between our observed density points

```
f0 <- approxfun(d0$x, d0$y)
f1 <- approxfun(d1$x, d1$y)
```

Next we find the x range of the overlap of the densities

```
ovrng <- c(max(min(d0$x), min(d1$x)), min(max(d0$x), max(d1$x)))
```

and divide that into 500 sections

```
i <- seq(min(ovrng), max(ovrng), length.out=500)
```

Now we calculate the distance between the density curves

```
h <- f0(i)-f1(i)
```

and using the formula for the area of a trapezoid we add up the area for the regions where d1>d0

```
area<-sum( (h[-1]+h[-length(h)]) /2 *diff(i) *(h[-1]>=0+0))
# [1] 0.1957627
```

We can plot the region using

```
plot(d0, main="d0=black, d1=green")
lines(d1, col="green")
jj<-which(h>0 & seq_along(h) %% 5==0); j<-i[jj]; 
segments(j, f1(j), j, f1(j)+h[jj])
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you *could* always use parabolic fits, or Chebyshev polynomials, etc. :-) . oops- you asked this: `integrate` uses adaptive quadrature; there are several implementations of Simpson's rule.  Probably others I haven't found yet.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sure, there are lots of ways to calculate area like that. I just wasn't sure if there were any built in that I was just missing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to shade the area between two density plots and calculate the magnitude of that area.

```
# Create some fake data
set.seed(10)
dat = data.frame(x=c(rnorm(1000, 0, 5), rnorm(2000, 0, 1)), 
                 group=c(rep("Bad", 1000), rep("Good", 2000)))

# Plot densities
# Use y=..count.. to get counts on the vertical axis
p1 = ggplot(dat) +
       geom_density(aes(x=x, y=..count.., colour=group), lwd=1)
```

Some extra calculations to shade the area between the two density plots
(adapted from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643234/fill-region-between-two-loess-smoothed-lines-in-r-with-ggplot)):

```
pp1 = ggplot_build(p1)

# Create a new data frame with densities for the two groups ("Bad" and "Good")
dat2 = data.frame(x = pp1$data[[1]]$x[pp1$data[[1]]$group==1],
                 ymin=pp1$data[[1]]$y[pp1$data[[1]]$group==1],
                 ymax=pp1$data[[1]]$y[pp1$data[[1]]$group==2])

# We want ymax and ymin to differ only when the density of "Good" 
# is greater than the density of "Bad"
dat2$ymax[dat2$ymax < dat2$ymin] = dat2$ymin[dat2$ymax < dat2$ymin]

# Shade the area between "Good" and "Bad"
p1a = p1 +  
    geom_ribbon(data=dat2, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), fill='yellow', alpha=0.5)
```

Here are the two plots:

[image]

To get the area (number of values) in specific ranges of `Good` and `Bad`, use the `density` function on each group (or you can continue to work with the data pulled from `ggplot` as above, but this way you get more direct control over how the density distribution is generated):

```
## Calculate densities for Bad and Good. 
# Use same number of points and same x-range for each group, so that the density 
# values will line up. Use a higher value for n to get a finer x-grid for the density
# values. Use a power of 2 for n, because the density function rounds up to the nearest 
# power of 2 anyway.
bad = density(dat$x[dat$group=="Bad"], 
             n=1024, from=min(dat$x), to=max(dat$x))
good = density(dat$x[dat$group=="Good"], 
             n=1024, from=min(dat$x), to=max(dat$x))

## Normalize so that densities sum to number of rows in each group

# Number of rows in each group
counts = tapply(dat$x, dat$group, length)

bad$y = counts[1]/sum(bad$y) * bad$y
good$y = counts[2]/sum(good$y) * good$y

## Results

# Number of "Good" in region where "Good" exceeds "Bad"
sum(good$y[good$y > bad$y])
[1] 1931.495  # Out of 2000 total in the data frame

# Number of "Bad" in region where "Good" exceeds "Bad"
sum(bad$y[good$y > bad$y])
[1] 317.7315  # Out of 1000 total in the data frame
```