# geom_ribbon error: Aesthetics must either be length one

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

My question is similar to [Fill region between two loess-smoothed lines in R with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643234/fill-region-between-two-loess-smoothed-lines-in-r-with-ggplot])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzRbi.png)

But I have two groups.

```
g1<-ggplot(NVIQ_predict,aes(cogn.age, predict, color=as.factor(NVIQ_predict$group)))+
    geom_smooth(aes(x = cogn.age, y = upper,group=group),se=F)+
    geom_line(aes(linetype = group), size = 0.8)+
    geom_smooth(aes(x = cogn.age, y = lower,group=group),se=F)
```

[image]

I want to fill red and blue for each group.

I tried:

```
gg1 <- ggplot_build(g1)   
df2 <- data.frame(x = gg1$data[[1]]$x,
                  ymin = gg1$data[[1]]$y,
                  ymax = gg1$data[[3]]$y)     
g1 + geom_ribbon(data = df2, aes(x = x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),fill = "grey", alpha = 0.4)
```

But it gave me the error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems

I get the same error every time my geom_ribbon() data and ggplot() data differ.

Can somebody help me with it? Thank you so much!

My data looks like:

```
  > NVIQ_predict
   cogn.age  predict     upper    lower group
1         7 39.04942  86.68497 18.00000     1
2         8 38.34993  82.29627 18.00000     1
3        10 37.05174  74.31657 18.00000     1
4        11 36.45297  70.72421 18.00000     1
5        12 35.88770  67.39555 18.00000     1
6        13 35.35587  64.32920 18.00000     1
7        14 34.85738  61.52322 18.00000     1
8        16 33.95991  56.68024 18.00000     1
9        17 33.56057  54.63537 18.00000     1
10       18 33.19388  52.83504 18.00000     1
11       19 32.85958  51.27380 18.00000     1
12       20 32.55752  49.94791 18.00000     1
13       21 32.28766  48.85631 18.00000     1
14       24 31.67593  47.09206 18.00000     1
15       25 31.53239  46.91136 18.00000     1
16       28 31.28740  48.01764 18.00000     1
17       32 31.36627  50.55201 18.00000     1
18       35 31.73386  53.19630 18.00000     1
19       36 31.91487  54.22624 18.00000     1
20       37 32.13026  55.25721 18.00000     1
21       38 32.38237  56.26713 18.00000     1
22       40 32.98499  58.36229 18.00000     1
23       44 34.59044  62.80187 18.00000     1
24       45 35.06804  64.01951 18.00000     1
25       46 35.57110  65.31888 18.00000     1
26       47 36.09880  66.64696 17.93800     1
27       48 36.72294  67.60053 17.97550     1
28       49 37.39182  68.49995 18.03062     1
29       50 38.10376  69.35728 18.10675     1
30       51 38.85760  70.17693 18.18661     1
31       52 39.65347  70.95875 18.27524     1
32       53 40.49156  71.70261 18.38020     1
33       54 41.35332  72.44006 17.90682     1
34       59 46.37849  74.91802 18.63206     1
35       60 47.53897  75.66218 19.64432     1
36       61 48.74697  76.43933 20.82346     1
37       63 51.30607  78.02426 23.73535     1
38       71 63.43129  86.05467 40.43482     1
39       72 65.15618  87.44794 42.72704     1
40       73 66.92714  88.95324 45.01966     1
41       84 89.42079 114.27939 68.03834     1
42       85 91.73831 117.44007 69.83676     1
43        7 33.69504  54.03695 15.74588     2
44        8 34.99931  53.96500 18.00533     2
45       10 37.61963  54.05684 22.43516     2
46       11 38.93493  54.21969 24.60049     2
47       12 40.25315  54.45963 26.73027     2
48       13 41.57397  54.77581 28.82348     2
49       14 42.89710  55.16727 30.87982     2
50       16 45.54954  56.17193 34.88453     2
51       17 46.87877  56.78325 36.83632     2
52       18 48.21025  57.46656 38.75807     2
53       19 49.54461  58.22266 40.65330     2
54       20 50.88313  59.05509 42.52505     2
55       21 52.22789  59.97318 44.36944     2
56       24 56.24397  63.21832 49.26963     2
57       25 57.55394  64.33850 50.76938     2
58       28 61.45282  68.05043 54.85522     2
59       32 66.44875  72.85234 60.04517     2
60       35 69.96560  76.06171 63.86949     2
61       36 71.09268  77.06821 65.11714     2
62       37 72.19743  78.04559 66.34927     2
63       38 73.28041  78.99518 67.56565     2
64       40 75.37861  80.81593 69.94129     2
65       44 79.29028  84.20275 74.37780     2
66       45 80.20272  85.00888 75.39656     2
67       46 81.08645  85.80180 76.37110     2
68       47 81.93696  86.57689 77.29704     2
69       48 82.75920  87.34100 78.17739     2
70       49 83.55055  88.09165 79.00945     2
71       50 84.30962  88.82357 79.79567     2
72       51 85.03743  89.53669 80.53817     2
73       52 85.73757  90.23223 81.24291     2
74       53 86.41419  90.91607 81.91232     2
75       54 87.05716  91.58632 82.52800     2
76       59 89.75923  94.58218 84.93629     2
77       60 90.18557  95.05573 85.31541     2
78       61 90.58166  95.51469 85.64864     2
79       63 91.27115  96.31107 86.23124     2
80       71 92.40983  98.35031 86.46934     2
81       72 92.36362  98.52258 86.20465     2
82       73 92.27734  98.67161 85.88308     2
83       84 88.66150  98.84699 78.47602     2
84       85 88.08846  98.73625 77.44067     2
```

According to  Gregor, I tried inherit.aes = FALSE, the error is gone. But my plot looks like:

[image]

Comment: Try setting `inherit.aes = FALSE` inside `geom_ribbon`. If that doesn't work, share some data to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks a lot! I tried inherit.aes = FALSE. R didn't give me any error, but the plot doesn't look right.

Comment: Side note: strangely, I even cannot produce the `g1` object (`ggplot2` version `1.0.1`). I get an `Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to linetype`.

Comment: best to share your data with `dput()`. Given your "continuous variable" error you might have a numeric where you should have a factor. Please replace your `NVIQ_predict` with the output from `dput(NVIQ_predict)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've got all the info we need. Now we just need to, ahem, connect the dots ;-)

First the input data:

```
NVIQ_predict <- read.table(text = "
                id  cogn.age  predict    upper    lower    group
                 1         7 39.04942  86.68497 18.00000     1
                 2         8 38.34993  82.29627 18.00000     1
                 3        10 37.05174  74.31657 18.00000     1
                 4        11 36.45297  70.72421 18.00000     1
                 5        12 35.88770  67.39555 18.00000     1
                 6        13 35.35587  64.32920 18.00000     1
                 7        14 34.85738  61.52322 18.00000     1
                 8        16 33.95991  56.68024 18.00000     1
                 9        17 33.56057  54.63537 18.00000     1
                 10       18 33.19388  52.83504 18.00000     1
                 11       19 32.85958  51.27380 18.00000     1
                 12       20 32.55752  49.94791 18.00000     1
                 13       21 32.28766  48.85631 18.00000     1
                 14       24 31.67593  47.09206 18.00000     1
                 15       25 31.53239  46.91136 18.00000     1
                 16       28 31.28740  48.01764 18.00000     1
                 17       32 31.36627  50.55201 18.00000     1
                 18       35 31.73386  53.19630 18.00000     1
                 19       36 31.91487  54.22624 18.00000     1
                 20       37 32.13026  55.25721 18.00000     1
                 21       38 32.38237  56.26713 18.00000     1
                 22       40 32.98499  58.36229 18.00000     1
                 23       44 34.59044  62.80187 18.00000     1
                 24       45 35.06804  64.01951 18.00000     1
                 25       46 35.57110  65.31888 18.00000     1
                 26       47 36.09880  66.64696 17.93800     1
                 27       48 36.72294  67.60053 17.97550     1
                 28       49 37.39182  68.49995 18.03062     1
                 29       50 38.10376  69.35728 18.10675     1
                 30       51 38.85760  70.17693 18.18661     1
                 31       52 39.65347  70.95875 18.27524     1
                 32       53 40.49156  71.70261 18.38020     1
                 33       54 41.35332  72.44006 17.90682     1
                 34       59 46.37849  74.91802 18.63206     1
                 35       60 47.53897  75.66218 19.64432     1
                 36       61 48.74697  76.43933 20.82346     1
                 37       63 51.30607  78.02426 23.73535     1
                 38       71 63.43129  86.05467 40.43482     1
                 39       72 65.15618  87.44794 42.72704     1
                 40       73 66.92714  88.95324 45.01966     1
                 41       84 89.42079 114.27939 68.03834     1
                 42       85 91.73831 117.44007 69.83676     1
                 43        7 33.69504  54.03695 15.74588     2
                 44        8 34.99931  53.96500 18.00533     2
                 45       10 37.61963  54.05684 22.43516     2
                 46       11 38.93493  54.21969 24.60049     2
                 47       12 40.25315  54.45963 26.73027     2
                 48       13 41.57397  54.77581 28.82348     2
                 49       14 42.89710  55.16727 30.87982     2
                 50       16 45.54954  56.17193 34.88453     2
                 51       17 46.87877  56.78325 36.83632     2
                 52       18 48.21025  57.46656 38.75807     2
                 53       19 49.54461  58.22266 40.65330     2
                 54       20 50.88313  59.05509 42.52505     2
                 55       21 52.22789  59.97318 44.36944     2
                 56       24 56.24397  63.21832 49.26963     2
                 57       25 57.55394  64.33850 50.76938     2
                 58       28 61.45282  68.05043 54.85522     2
                 59       32 66.44875  72.85234 60.04517     2
                 60       35 69.96560  76.06171 63.86949     2
                 61       36 71.09268  77.06821 65.11714     2
                 62       37 72.19743  78.04559 66.34927     2
                 63       38 73.28041  78.99518 67.56565     2
                 64       40 75.37861  80.81593 69.94129     2
                 65       44 79.29028  84.20275 74.37780     2
                 66       45 80.20272  85.00888 75.39656     2
                 67       46 81.08645  85.80180 76.37110     2
                 68       47 81.93696  86.57689 77.29704     2
                 69       48 82.75920  87.34100 78.17739     2
                 70       49 83.55055  88.09165 79.00945     2
                 71       50 84.30962  88.82357 79.79567     2
                 72       51 85.03743  89.53669 80.53817     2
                 73       52 85.73757  90.23223 81.24291     2
                 74       53 86.41419  90.91607 81.91232     2
                 75       54 87.05716  91.58632 82.52800     2
                 76       59 89.75923  94.58218 84.93629     2
                 77       60 90.18557  95.05573 85.31541     2
                 78       61 90.58166  95.51469 85.64864     2
                 79       63 91.27115  96.31107 86.23124     2
                 80       71 92.40983  98.35031 86.46934     2
                 81       72 92.36362  98.52258 86.20465     2
                 82       73 92.27734  98.67161 85.88308     2
                 83       84 88.66150  98.84699 78.47602     2
                 84       85 88.08846  98.73625 77.44067     2", header = TRUE)
NVIQ_predict$id <- NULL
```

Make sure the `group` column is a factor variable, so we can use it as a line type.

```
NVIQ_predict$group <- as.factor(NVIQ_predict$group)
```

Then build the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

g1 <- ggplot(NVIQ_predict, aes(cogn.age, predict, color=group)) + 
             geom_smooth(aes(x = cogn.age, y = upper, group=group), method = loess, se = FALSE) + 
             geom_smooth(aes(x = cogn.age, y = lower, group=group), method = loess, se = FALSE) +
             geom_line(aes(linetype = group), size = 0.8)
```

Finally, extract the `(x,ymin)` and `(x,ymax)` coordinates of the curves for group 1 as well as group 2. These pairs have identical x-coordinates, so connecting those points mimics shading the areas between both curves. This was explained in [Fill region between two loess-smoothed lines in R with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643234/fill-region-between-two-loess-smoothed-lines-in-r-with-ggplot]). The only difference here is that we need to be a bit more careful to select and connect the points that belong to the *correct* curves...

```
gp <- ggplot_build(g1)  

d1 <- gp$data[[1]]
d2 <- gp$data[[2]]

df1 <- data.frame(x    = d1[d1$group == 1,]$x,
                  ymin = d2[d2$group == 1,]$y,
                  ymax = d1[d1$group == 1,]$y)   

df2 <- data.frame(x    = d1[d1$group == 2,]$x,
                  ymin = d2[d2$group == 2,]$y,
                  ymax = d1[d1$group == 2,]$y)   

g1 + geom_ribbon(data = df1, aes(x = x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = "grey", alpha = 0.4) + 
     geom_ribbon(data = df2, aes(x = x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = "grey", alpha = 0.4)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]